# How to assemble USB-C power connector?

Tags: usb-c, mechanical-assembly, power-connector

I bought a few USB-C power connectors to reuse old power supplies with new Raspberry Pi power socket standard. Here is the original picture:

[image]

When I try to assemble it by merging these together:

[image]

the connector will slide into its housing when inserted into socket (see the left side):

[image]

Advice I received from the vendor is: 你需要先把USB头放进去，然后两边再合并一起, which Google translates as *You need to put the USB head in first, and then merge the two sides together*. I tried all permutations of assembly order, and it doesn't work. Additionally, someone on youtube illustrates the same problem: https://youtu.be/lCOS-VHTu4c?t=285. He gave up and used hot glue. Is there a solution without using an adhesive?

Comment: Ultrasonic welding? I mean...if there's no visible mechanism to snap it together to begin with then even if it didn't slide into the housing upon plugging in, nothing would be stopping it from pulling on de-insertion.

Comment: @DKNguyen There is a catch in the housing to prevent the "O" ring to slide inside, but it comes out easily. It looks like a case of reverse engineering gone wrong.

Comment: Cheap product sloppy tolerances. Buy a different one?

Comment: @Passerby I will make it work with crazy-glue and hot glue. Just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: Actually I think "merge" means glue.

Comment: Has anyone come up with an actual answer to this? Who is the manufacturer? Do they have a web page? Instructions somewhere?

Comment: @JohnTaylor I gave up. Finding a manufacturer for a cheap Chinese part like this one is practically impossible. It's a risk of buying directly from Asia.

Answer (score 1):

You Could try some hot glue, don’t apply too much ‘though. It should be sufficient for this type of applications like you gave.